# MYSQL Error 1064 in Primary and Unique Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Good day. I am trying to add a `suppliers` table on my database and when i try to save, it throws this error.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`supp_id`), UNIQUE `supp_name` (`supp_name`))' at line 1

I have attached my SQL statement.

```
CREATE TABLE `project_inv`.`suppliers` ( 
    `supp_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `supp_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `supp_addr` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL , 
    `supp_phone` INT(20) NOT NULL , 
    `supp_email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `supp_notes` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL , 
    `status` ENUM(0) NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`supp_id`), 
    UNIQUE `supp_name` (`supp_name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I think its something with my UNIQUE key but i really can't figure out what the error is. Any form of help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you cannot format the question so its readable, it begs the question, why would we bother reading it

Comment: `ENUM('0')` ... voting to close as a typo question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I'm sorry but I tried countless times to format the question as you corrected it but I didn't get it right. Please how did you put the Yellow highlight around the error code? Also I tried to put the SQL statement in a single block but I couldn't. I also followed the More formatting options link but I didn't quite get it. When hit the enter button after each line, it turns out like a new block of code. Please show me what to do, if you can. Thanks

Comment: A simple `>` in column 1

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly I added `>` to the column 1 and it didn't result in the text highlighting and justification that you applied to my block of code. A little clarification will help. Also please, how do i apply the yellow highlight?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , it's not a typo question. I tried to used phpMyAdmin to create the database. I have encountered this issue before and i had to use `PREVIEW SQL` to solve it but i didn't know it was a bug in phpMyAdmin as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874215/why-phpmyadmin-does-not-create-values-for-enum-type). It's a bug question, not a typo question.

Comment: All you have to do is press the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63119632/edit) link under the question. You will then see the `>` in front of the error message. I do not see a yellow background, that formatting was removed a month or so ago, well it was for me and I thought for everybody. But I am no expert on the workings of SO

Comment: @Riggsfolly, I have seen the `>` Also please how do I format the code to be in a single block just as you did mine?

Answer (score 1):

It is not about the `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` declaration, but about `ENUM()`: it expects string literals, so you would need to surround the values in the list with single quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE `project_inv`.`suppliers` ( 
    `supp_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `supp_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `supp_addr` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL , 
    `supp_phone` INT(20) NOT NULL , 
    `supp_email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `supp_notes` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL , 
    `status` ENUM('0') NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`supp_id`), 
    UNIQUE `supp_name` (`supp_name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

However having a non-nullable `ENUM()` column with just one value allowed makes little sense - basically you are forcing every row to have the same value (`'0'`). So either add more values to the list... or just remove the column.

Comment: Thank you, @GMB. It worked. I did `ENUM('1','0') NOT NULL , ` Actually i just realized that it was a bug with some versions of phpMyAdmin. In these versions, using phpMyAdmin to populate the ENUM datatype doesn't work. It has to be manually input with SQL. See [here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12480)

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using string inside enum i used 'N' instated 0

```
CREATE TABLE `project_inv`.`suppliers` ( 
    `supp_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `supp_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `supp_addr` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL , 
    `supp_phone` INT(20) NOT NULL , 
    `supp_email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `supp_notes` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL , 
    `status` ENUM('N') NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`supp_id`), 
    UNIQUE `supp_name` (`supp_name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```